# Spring Security + REST controller Post method not displaying username

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security

I am using spring boot with spring security as authentication for my web application.
I have a controller which takes authenticationRequest(POJO) parameters as  @RequestBody

Calling end point /authenticate from postman by passing username and password in JSON format
But when I print the values(both username and password) I can only see password getting printed. After many attempts couldn't find the reason why username is not populating.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/authenticate",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<?> createAuthenticationToken(@RequestBody AuthenticationRequest authenticationRequest) throws Exception{


    System.out.println("authenticationRequest.getUserName()"+authenticationRequest.getUserName());
    System.out.println("authenticationRequest.getPassword()"+authenticationRequest.getPassword());

    authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authenticationRequest.getUserName(), authenticationRequest.getPassword()));

        
}
```

POJO Class

```
public class AuthenticationRequest {
    
private String username;
private String password;

public AuthenticationRequest(){
    
}
public AuthenticationRequest(String username, String password) {
    super();
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
}
public String getUserName() {
    return username;
}
public void setUserName(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
```

}

JSON (raw)
{
"username":"user",
"password":"pass"
}

Console

```
authenticationRequest.getUserName()null
authenticationRequest.getPassword()pass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your getter and setter:

```
public String getUserName() {
    return username;
}
public void setUserName(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}
```

The letter n should be small because your JSON contains `username` with small n. Try like this:

```
public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}
```